# How to loop through folder & sub-folder to open a file?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open an Excel file with a variable name that I pre-defined.

File name will be PIF_08.31.2018 based on this month but next month file name will be PIF_09.30.2018. I want to look in folder and sub-folder and open the file specified.

I get an error which says file is not found but clearly it is in the sub-folder.

I suspect my code didn't go into any folders or didn't go into the subfolders.

Structure of my folders are Main -> Year (i.e. 2018) -> Month (i.e. 08 August).

In each month folder, I have 2 files and I want to open the one specified.

```
Sub test()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    HostFolder = "S:\Main\"
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim CurrFile
    Dim fname
    Dim folderpath
    Dim File       
    fname = "PIF_" & Format(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now, -2), "MM.D.YYYY") & ".xlsx"
    'PIF_08.31.2018
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.subfolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next   
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If File.Name = fname Then
            Workbooks.Open (File.Path)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You never include the name of the folder (or subfolder) in the `fname`. It's always looking in the same folder for the file, and if it's not in that folder it will always fail.

Comment: I want vba to detect for me which I am not going to specify. How can I fix my codes so it will work?

Comment: You need to add the full path to `Workbooks.Open (fname)`. The `FileSystemObject` might be looking in your search path, but Excel certainly isn't.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the portion of my codes where I ask excel to open to `Workbooks.Open(File.Path)` and it is working, is this correct?

Comment: VBA won't change the folder for you automatically. You need to add it to the front of `fname` before checking the existence of the file. If `File.Name` is `C:\Temp\Somefile.xlsx`, and `fname` is only `Somefile.xlsx`, they will never match.

Comment: You could change VBA:s folder with `ChDir`.  Also, I assume the filenames in your question are incorrect since they are missing valid extensions?

Answer (score 0):

## I don't understand this code!?

I'm using Excel 2003 and there is no EoMonth function but from what I've read you're using it probably fine except you have used "MM.D.YYYY" instead of "**MM.DD.YYYY**". If that doesn't solve your problem (it shouldn't) then maybe VBA 'translates' the dates differently. In any case I wouldn't bother because you can achieve all this using just **VBA** (without EoMonth):

```
fname = "PIF_" & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), (Month(Date) + 1) - 2, 0), _
    "MM.DD.YYYY") & ".xlsx"
```

I've adjusted it so you can use it similarly like the EoMonth function (notice the '**- 2**').

BTW the code loops several times from the beginning to the end until it finally finds and opens the workbook.

May first impression was this cannot possibly work, but it's working. So I ask you to elaborate a little bit, I really don't understand how this code is working!?

Comment: Thank you and when I used `Workbooks.Open (File.Path)` it works just fine so I don't have to specify an actual folder or path.